# Appium installation getting error

Tags: apt, ruby

I install appium via:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential curl git m4 ruby texinfo libbz2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libexpat-dev libncurses-dev zlib1g-dev
```

Install linux brew:Paste the below command at terminal and hit enter

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew/go/install)"
set path for brew
```

Type: gedit .bashrc at terminal and copy paste following into the .bashrc file

```
export PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"
export MANPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/man:$MANPATH"
export INFOPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/info:$INFOPATH"
```

Install node:Paste the below commands one by one at terminal and hit enter

```
brew update
brew install node
brew link node
```

Install appium

```
npm install -g appium
npm install wd
```

To start appium: Paste the below command at terminal and hit enter

```
appium
```

Showing like this:

```
naveen@naveen-Inspiron-3542:~$ appium
/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory
naveen@naveen-Inspiron-3542:~$ appium &
[1] 15394
naveen@naveen-Inspiron-3542:~$ /usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: what system is this?

Comment: @George Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: So the _brew_  is Ubuntu too?

Comment: @George  Can you help me ?

Comment: `node` not in your path in the `.bashrc` file, pls run `which node` ans post the result

Comment: And also `which nodejs`

Comment: @George   Thanks for the support .appium is installed

Comment: Is the issue resolved, and how did you achieve this. Please post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55465/discussion-between-comrade-and-george).

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial will helpful for everyone those who struggle to install appium server on ubuntu machine.
http://steelkiwi.com/blog/setup-environment-mobile-android-app-testing-linux/

And also  add  `vim .bashrc`   put this file and save

```
export PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"

export MANPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/man:$MANPATH"

export INFOPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/info:$INFOPATH"`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download "npm install -g appium-doctor" and run that "appium-doctor --android" then you can see what you missed.